# Importing Unpublished Variable Products Loses Price

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using the stock WooCommerce CSV import with a whole range of products, and the "Published" column I have all got set to `0`.

They all (Simple and Variable) come in as private, however, the variable products don't come in with their price.  It isn't until I go into one of them, press "Update" and it fixes that entries price.

WTAF...

If I load it in again, all set to `1` for Published - all the prices are fine.

Versions:

```
Wordpress: 5.0.3
WooCommerce: 3.5.4
```

Answer (score 0):

Raised as an issue on GitHub; the variations were also being loaded as unpublished so it left those as disabled.

Updated the CSV export to leave those rows as `1` for published.

[Issue ID: #22657](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/22657)